# Tomcat ignores X-Forwarded-Proto behind an Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, reverse

My Tomcat server sits behind an Apache reverse proxy. Although everything seems to be configured properly, `request.isSecure()` returns `false`.

#### Apache configuration

Apache runs on the same machine as Tomcat.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

#### Tomcat valve (server.xml)

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" 
               internalProxies="127.0.0.1" 
               remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" 
               proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by" 
               protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />
```

Upon further inspection, Tomcat does receive the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header with `https`. However there must be a misconfiguration with the valve above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the RemoteIpValve docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html), Tomcat **always checks** that `req.getRemoteAddr()` fits either the `internalProxies` or the `trustedProxies` of the valve.

Make sure that this remote address fits the one you set in the valve. If the proxy uses an **IPv6 address** (`0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`), `127.0.0.1` won't work.

Instead, do not override `internalProxies` as the default regex works pretty well, e.g. :

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" 
               remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" 
               proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by" 
               protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" 
               internalProxies="127\.0\.0\.1" 
               remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" 
               proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by" 
               protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**